# Return Promise from Recursive function in Ionic 2 / Type Script / Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, ionic2, promise

I have async recursive function and that takes some time to execute.

See following two functions

```
public sendAndRecivesMessage(content:string, finalMessage:Message, outMessageCount:number = 1){
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.doSendAndRecivesMessage(content, finalMessage, outMessageCount);
            console.log("Have to wait until above function finish executing");
            resolve (finalMessage);
        });
        return this.promise;
    }

private doSendAndRecivesMessage(content:string, finalMessage:Message, outMessageCount:number = 1){

        let newContent = IREDMART_KEYWORD + APP_IDENTITY + outMessageCount + " " + content;
        let message:Message = new Message(newContent, API_END_POINT);

        this.sendMessage(message);

        let promise = this.recieveMessage();
        promise.then((message) => {
            let inMessageCount:number = message.content.split(MSG_COUNT_SEPARATOR)[1];
            finalMessage.content += message.content.split(MSG_COUNT_SEPARATOR)[2];
            if(inMessageCount == 1){
                finalMessage.reciever = message.reciever;
                finalMessage.date = message.date;
            }
            else{
                this.sendAndRecivesMessage(content, finalMessage, outMessageCount + 1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here `doSendAndRecivesMessage` function takes some time to execute and it is a recursive function.

in `sendAndRecivesMessage` function I need to wait until above function finishes its execution and have to return `finalMessage`

how Can I achieve this?

Also, I tried it as follows

```
public sendAndRecivesMessage(content:string, finalMessage:Message, outMessageCount:number = 1){

        let newContent = IREDMART_KEYWORD + APP_IDENTITY + outMessageCount + " " + content;
        let message:Message = new Message(newContent, API_END_POINT);

        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.sendMessage(message);

            let promise = this.recieveMessage();
            promise.then((message) => {
                let inMessageCount:number = message.content.split(MSG_COUNT_SEPARATOR)[1];
                finalMessage.content += message.content.split(MSG_COUNT_SEPARATOR)[2];
                if(inMessageCount == 1){
                    finalMessage.reciever = message.reciever;
                    finalMessage.date = message.date;
                    resolve(finalMessage);
                }
                else{
                    this.sendAndRecivesMessage(content, finalMessage, outMessageCount + 1);
                }
            });
        });

        return this.promise;
    }
```

But because of function is async and recursive the return promise does not contains resolved `finalMessage`.

Please give me a suggesion to overcome this issue.

Thanks

Comment: just to get this clear, you want to keep calling an asynchronous function until you get a specific response and then return something from that message?

Comment: Yes, When the message inMessageCount == 1, I have to return the finalMessage, Otherwise have to call function itself by increasing value of outMessageCount, 
The logic is receiving messages has inMessageCount like ...,3,2,1. I have to concat all message bodies until inMessageCount = 1 message receives. Then have to return finalMessage.

Comment: I added an example, maybe it will help figure out how to structure your code. if not let me know we can go deeper. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is working now....  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the entire thing as a train (a promise train) and the functions you want to call as wagons in that train. All you have to do is connect them in the right order.

There are two ways of connecting wagons to the train. One is by giving a callback to the `then` function of a promise. The second is by returning another promise in one of the callbacks.

Here's an example of how you could structure your code:

```js
function randomNumber() {
    // a function that can later return a value
    return Promise.resolve(Math.random());
}

// recursive function, keeps calling itself until the condition is met
function collectValues(until, previous) {
    // call the async function return a promise
    return randomNumber().then((value) => {
        // when we get a number we check the condition
        console.log(`prev:${previous} new:${value}`);
        let result = previous + value;
        if (result > until) {
            // when satisfied just return the final message
            return result;
        } else {
            // return the promise from the next recursive call with new params
            return collectValues(until, result);
        }
    });
}

collectValues(5, 0).then(console.log);
```